# Jira: How to set Assignee to match parent's Custom Field Value

Tags: groovy, jira, jira-plugin

I'm using Jira and the Script Runner plugin to Create a sub-task on transition. That's all working well. However, I cannot seem to set the 'Assignee' of the Subtask to match the value of the 'Project Manager' listed on the parent (I believe this is a custom field). Below is what I am using, But it does not work. **What is the correct way to write this?**:

`issue.assignee = transientVars["originalissueobject"].cfValues['Project Manager']`

---

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ACG, I wasn't able to get your answer to work, but I found a very similar script here﻿ that worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help!

```
import com.atlassian.jira.user.ApplicationUsers
cfParent = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectByName('Project Manager')
parentMyFieldValue = transientVars["issue"].getCustomFieldValue(cfParent)
issue.setAssignee(ApplicationUsers.toDirectoryUser(parentMyFieldValue))
```

For those looking at this answer with a similar problem. Place this code in the "Additional Issue Action" Box within Script Runner's "Create Subtask" Post Function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
issue.assignee= ApplicationUsers.toDirectoryUser(cfValues['Project Manager'])
```